# Need to get a return string value from a function involving an if-else loop

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong? I have a slider. I get my values from it. Then I have a function where I want to get a specific string value depending on the value from the slider. As long as the if-else loop does not exist, I get the return string. But of course, I need the if-else. I am sure I am doing something wrong but can not seem to put my finger on it.

A little guidance would be much appreciated.

```
var time_slider = new rSlider({
        target: '#timeslider',
        values: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
        range:    false, 
        set:      null, 
        width:    null,
        scale:    true,
        labels:   true,
        tooltip:  false,
        step:     null, 
        disabled: false, 
        onChange: function (value) {
            return rent_data(time_value = value)
        }
});

function rent_data(){ 
    if (time_value == 2012){ 
        return 'Rent_2012';
    }
/*  else if (time_value == 2013){
        data = 'Rent_2013';
    }
    else if (time_value == 2014){
        data = 'Rent_2014';
    }
    else if (time_value == 2015){
        data = 'Rent_2015';
    }
    else if (time_value == 2016){
        data = 'Rent_2016';
    }
    else if (time_value == 2017){
        data = 'Rent_2017';
    }*/
    //return data;
}   

console.log('DATA  ' + rent_data())
```

Comment: try doing `return rent_data(value)` instead of `return rent_data(time_value = value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next code with some debug including:

```
var time_slider = new rSlider({
    target: '#timeslider',
    values: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
    range: false,
    set: null,
    width: null,
    scale: true,
    labels: true,
    tooltip: false,
    step: null,
    disabled: false,
    onChange: function (value) {
        console.log("Slider value changed to: " + value);
        return rent_data(value);
    }
});

function rent_data(value)
{
    var rentValue = "Rent_" + value;
    console.log("rent_data() will return: " + rentValue);
    return rentValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this is still not giving me the string I guess. Since it's not creating the desired result! 
But thanks... it's at least a starting point

Comment: What did you see on the developer console? If you explain a little more, i can help you solve your problem...

Comment: The console shows the correct values. But 'Rent_2012' is an attribute from the geojson that I want to refer to... so even though console shows me Rent_2012, it still is not fetching the data I require.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have the needed background for understand what your real problem is and the context you are working on. Maybe, in the onChange callback of your slider, you should call a method that retrieve your required data using the generated string, like: `getDataFromGeoJson("Rent_" + value)`.